# How do I route :collection to use /controller/action/:id in rails 2.3 & 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have code that looks like this:

```
:collection => {
  :download_print_use => :get
}
```

rake routes dosn't show me how to use :id to map to something like /controller/download_print_use/:id

what do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's the point of the collection option. Ex: `events/download_print`.

I think you need to use `:member => {}` to get what you want.

---

It's the same principle in rails 3, but with a more elegant syntax. You can read this paragraph to understand it better: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions